# Ripple Effect On ImageView not triggering

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, material-design

I have a `RecyclerView` with `ImageView`s in each item.

I set `onClickListener` for the `ImageView`s in `onBindViewHolder` as follows:

```
holder.starIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: logic
        }
    });
```

The ripple effect worked fine until I added the following logic to `onClick`. This logic changes the `Drawable` for the `ImageView`.

```
holder.starIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == holder.starIV.getId()) {
                ListItem clickedItem = mDataset.get(position);
                ListItem updatedItem = new ListItem(clickedItem);
                if (clickedItem.getStarState() == STAR_ON) {
                    updatedItem.setStarState(STAR_OFF);
                    updatedItem.setStarDrawable(
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                            v.getContext(),R.drawable.ic_star_border_24px));
                }
                else if (clickedItem.getStarState() == STAR_OFF) {
                    updatedItem.setStarState(STAR_ON);
                    updatedItem.setStarDrawable(
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                            v.getContext(),R.drawable.ic_star_24px));
                }
                mDataset.set(position,updatedItem);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Now, I get **no** ripple effect at all. Here's the XML for the `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_star"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_border_24px"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
/>
```

The ripple effect works normally again when i comment out the logic part in `onClick`.

**Have I implemented the above correctly?**

**What change would you suggest to get the ripple effect working correctly?**

**EDIT:** It appears that changing the `Drawable` is interfering with the ripple animation. So i moved all the logic to an `AsyncTask` with a small delay to allow the animation to finish. This seems to **work**, but I feel this solution is not elegant. Here's the `AsyncTask`:

```
    class DoLogix extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        try{Thread.sleep(125);}catch (Exception e) {}
        publishProgress(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... val) {
        ListItem clickedItem = mDataset.get(val[0]);
        ListItem updatedItem = new ListItem(clickedItem);
        if (clickedItem.getStarState() == STAR_ON) {
            updatedItem.setStarState(STAR_OFF);
            updatedItem.setStarDrawable(starBorder);
        }
        else if (clickedItem.getStarState() == STAR_OFF) {
            updatedItem.setStarState(STAR_ON);
            updatedItem.setStarDrawable(star);
        }
        mDataset.set(val[0],updatedItem);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u can set a ripple drawable as the foreground of ur imageview.

Comment: I tried your solution. There was no change in the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

add below code to your parent layout

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It appears that the ripple effect is triggering only when I tap in the parent layout's area excluding the ImageView.

Comment: try to put focusable=false and focusableintouchmode=false to imageview in xml.